# How to format numbers in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
( SELECT SUM(misyukko.dataint11) 
   FROM misyukko 
   where syouhinid='$kokyakuorderbango'
) AS total_amount
```

For Example:

If the sum is `12345` it will be displayed as `123,45`

If the sum is `12345678` it will be displayed as `123,456,78`

How to solve it?

Comment: That's not a SQL task. Fix it in the presentation.

Comment: BTW, 1234 usually is shown as 1,234.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT 12345 AS num
)

SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(num::text, '(\d{3})', '\1,', 'g'), ',') AS num_out
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo